# Logic App Dynamics Connector - Record Updated - Which fields have changed?

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I am building an integration system using Logic Apps connector to get details of updated records in Dynamics.

I only want to take action when certain fields have changed.

My problem is that the output from the connector shows all the fields after the record is updated.

I'd like to know which fields have changed so my Logic App can decide whether or not to take action.

Does anybody have any ideas? I was thinking of triggering the logic app via HTTP POST and post from inside a custom workflow activity when certain fields change but I wanted to hear if anyone has a better solution first using just the Logic App with Dynamics connector.

Answer (score 2):

Logic app connector for Dynamics 365 exposing triggers which has record level checkpoints like **create/update/delete** but does not have field level filtering granularity.

Probably your decision is correct by going with Custom WF activity or a Plugin that triggers on filtering attributes of your choice, then invoking Logic app within Plugin/WF using HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

[Replacement **Dataverse** connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/) has ability to trigger based on [specific changed fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/#when-a-row-is-added,-modified-or-deleted) using following options:

> - `Select columns` - filteringattributes - string: Enter a comma-separated list of column unique names. The flow triggers if any of them are
>   modified
> - `Filter rows` - filterexpression - string: Odata expression to limit rows that can trigger the flow, eg. statecode eq 0

---

**Note:** [As of 2022-Nov] The new connector is not yet available for LogicApps.

> "[Microsoft Dataverse (legacy) connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataservice) will be supported by Microsoft until the [Microsoft Dataverse connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/) supports Logic Apps."

The new connector is available in PowerApps - the experience was 99% identical, difference appears to be a different billing/organizational model than Azure Logic Apps.